# How to use the same NSCache Image from tableVIew Cell to push it on a Static tableVIew

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, tableview, nscache

silly question maybe but, what's the best practice to use the same NSCache image from my initial tableVIew Cell to push it on a static TableView, right now i'm using the same approach on my tableVIew to get the image on my static tableView

1) I have a tableView where I load all the images from a web service, I cache this images on the simulator
2) when I select a cell from the initial tableView,I had the same information from the tableViewCell on a static tableView, my problem is how to use the same image from my initial tableVIewCell from the cache on my static tableView ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Explain the question. You question isn't clear

Comment: Do you require lazyloading or what?

Comment: Yes, i'm doing a lazy loading, + I'm caching the images (please check my question updated)

Answer (score 0):

Same the images in key value dictionary with index path as key

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Can you be more specific  with an example ?

Answer (score 0):

AFNetworking has a category UIImageView+AFNetworking that will help to reduce code to download image and save it into NSCachedirectory as well as to display in tableview static cell

Answer (score 0):

I think that [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) is something you can look at.

It provides the downloading of images as well as image caching, it already has the option to use their imageView category:

```
//found on their github: i.e.
//Storing the image
[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] storeImage:myImage forKey:myCacheKey];
```

Then you just have to check if image is there based on the imageKey